# Accessing sharepoint search engine programatically using c#

Tags: fast-for-sharepoint

How can we perform a sharepoint 2007 search programatically?i.e. I wanna search the whole sharepoint site for a (suppose) hard coded string through coding and get the results.
When I'll be running the code it will access the sharepoint search engine and show me the search results.Please help me out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use SharePoint web service to do that.

[Corey Roth](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2008/07/17/how-to-query-search-using-the-web-service.aspx) have a tutorial about using SharePoint search web service.

MSDN also have article to use web service for enterprise search in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms543175%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can use Query Object Model Classes to do that.
[FullTextSqlQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.fulltextsqlquery%28v=office.14%29.aspx) Use this class to execute SQL syntax search queries.
QueryKeywordQuery Use this class to execute Keyword syntax search queries.

```
SearchServiceApplicationProxy proxy = (SearchServiceApplicationProxy)SearchServiceApplicationProxy.GetProxy(SPServiceContext.GetContext(SPContext.Current.Site));
KeywordQuery query = new KeywordQuery(proxy);
query.ResultsProvider = Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchProvider.Default;
query.QueryText = queryText;
query.ResultTypes |= ResultType.RelevantResults;
ResultTableCollection searchResults = query.Execute();
if (searchResults.Exists(ResultType.RelevantResults))
{
    ResultTable searchResult = searchResults[ResultType.RelevantResults];
    DataTable result = new DataTable();
    result.TableName = "Result";
    result.Load(searchResult, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
}
```

`FullTextSqlQuery` is available in two different namespaces. There is `Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Query.FullTextSqlQuery` for SharePoint Foundation and there is `Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.FullTextSqlQuery` for SharePoint Server.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost"))
{
  using (FullTextSqlQuery query = new FullTextSqlQuery(site))
  {

query.QueryText = "SELECT Title, FooText FROM scope() WHERE FooText = 'Foo2'";
query.ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults;

ResultTableCollection queryResults = query.Execute();
ResultTable queryResultsTable = queryResults[ResultType.RelevantResults];
DataTable queryDataTable = new DataTable();
queryDataTable.Load(queryResultsTable, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
```

}
}

[Custom Search Solutions for SharePoint 2010 - FullTextSqlQuery](http://arindamchat.blogspot.com/2013/06/custom-search-solutions-for-sharepoint.html)

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)